# How to notify windows OS to hold on releasing logonui, so that Credential provider can release the resources

Tags: c++, windows, credentials, msdn, winlogon

I am in process of developing a custom credential provider for windows 7. The CP include creation of browser control. The problem here is if the user decide to skip CP and perform windows logon, as the browser control is not destroyed, when windows takes back the control the logonUI is crashing. So I need a method to notify windows to hold on releasing the logonUI, meantime CP will free all its resources followed by notifying windows that we done and proceed with releasing the logonUI.

Thanks
Sindy